# Recommendations on MERN folder structure and where to define MongoDB connection

Tags: express, mongoose, mern

I am new to creating a full stack app with with MERN (using React instead of Angular as I am familiar with React). I've been looking at tutorials to learn how to separate my server-side code (express/mongo) apart as I initially had my Express routes, MongoDB connection, and API requests defined in my server.js file (Just to get something working).

Currently, my folder structure and the way I define my routes and db is as follows:

1. routes.js includes all routes I've defined in my routes folder and
   exports a routes function to be used in server.js
2. Use express.Router to define specific routes for a model (i.e user) inside routes folder. I also include MongoDB model here to perform any necessary actions (find, insert, etc)
3. Define mongo schema in userModel.js

At this point, I'm not sure where to connect my MongoDB. Before, I connected to the DB in server.js, but if I want use my models to query against my DB, do I define my connection inside every route file where I use a model? Is there a way for me to only call mongoose.connect once and ensure I'm always connected to my DB?

```
// Connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || db_url)
```

userRoutes.js

```
-root folder
    -public
    -src
        -server
            -db
            -models
                -userModel.js
            -routes
                -userRoutes.js
            -routes.js
    -server.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the mongoose connection in a separate file. Then link that connection using `let schema = require('_path_to_file_')` wherever you need to link to the database.

Answer (score 2):

I've often seen the following dir structure w.r.t full-stack JS apps

- root

  - client
  - server
  - common

Likewise I've seen a modified [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) approach implemented similar to the following

- root

  - src (contains the react/redux dirs - actions, comp, cont, reducers, store, etc.)
  - bin (compiled dist)
  - etc ("Editable Text Configuration" or "Extended Tool Chest")
  - public
  - package.json, readme, etc.

Answer (score 0):

folder structure to build API using MongoDB, Express, Node JS

- controllers
         /* user.controller.js
- models
      /* user.model.js
- routes
     /* user.route.js
- config
     /* database.js

/* server.js
/*package.json

```js
//database.js

  module.exports = {
          url:'mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name'
          }
```